# Is it possible to change accidental reviews for a short time after the review?

Tags: feature-request, review, undo

Often I visit CV via my mobile phone because during the day I am out for work, etc. With the smaller screen and the imperfections of a touch device I have experienced a few instances where I approved an edit or post without having the intention of doing so (rejections aren't the problem because there I have a follow-up screen before the review is final). As it has just happened again I have become sufficiently fed up with my phone in order to write this question.

Would it be possible to have a short period after a review in which it is still possible to change it? I'm talking about something like 10 seconds or so, such that this kind of mistake can be fixed immediately if one realizes that this has happened. After all we do allow for retraction of up/down votes on the site for a certain period as well.

Comment: I've done this too.

Comment: That would be nice. Regarding suggested-edits, ideally it would be good to review from smartphones only if one is comfortable typing and formatting stuff (which normally it is difficult with such devices). Because the improvement of the post can be compromised, if a suggestion is valid but still misses important edits.

Comment: For reviews that require more extensive editing there is also the skip button, so this shouldn't be the problem in this case.

Comment: While I am completely sympathetic to the wish (+1), one possibility is perhaps just to avoid tasks that aren't undo-able when on a device that's not currently especially suited to the task. Someone else can get them for a while. This is especially the case with suggested edits, which are currently as rare as hen's teeth. Someone else is sure to take care of it in very short time.

Comment: I think we should leave aside the fact that I tend to review often. The point is that CV is based on the internet which is becoming increasingly mobile. Saying "Don't participate if you're mobile, someone else will take care of it" is therefore not the best approach in my view. Allowing for the correction of small mistakes (that can equally happen with a computer but probably less frequently) would be a contribution to making CV more user-friendly.

Comment: @Andy My comment wasn't intended to suggest "you review too often" (I don't think you do), just that there are plenty of people doing it; the queues never seem to stick around long. I agree that the internet is becoming increasingly mobile (which is why I started with 'completely sympathetic to the wish'), and that the SE network should try to make that kind of access work better.

Comment: Sorry, I meant no offense. I only wanted to highlight the point again but you're right, it wasn't really necessary :)